# GRPC server: increase max inbound metadata size

Tags: c++, server, grpc

I create C++ GRPC server and try to connect to it by a client. I need to pass a large metadata (> 15 MB).
I found option max-inbound-metadata-size, but I don't know how it'll be installed in C++.

```
grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
builder.AddListeningPort(config_.address, GetCredentials());
builder.RegisterService(service_);
server_ = builder.BuildAndStart();
```

How to set server configurations in C++?

Answer (score 0):

[grpc_tool](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/dcad15d43ba301beb3d40ed312f03c64147de7b3/test/cpp/util/grpc_tool.cc#L245-L248) might be interesting to you to see how it can be configured.

Comment: This is a good solution, but for the channel (client). I am interested in the same parameter, but for the server mode